# Change div size without affecting the DOM

Tags: html, css

I am working on this grid-like user list and I am having trouble achieving my goal.
My goal is when you hover over the user's div, info about him will be displayed. I want the div to increase its size and overlap the other divs without breaking the DOM tree.

I hope you know what I mean .. :)

[image]

Comment: instead use jquery masonary

Comment: Use `z-index` property.

Comment: I've tried using z-index but with no luck.

Comment: I would think that z-index won't work because you have to absolutely position the element. I would use jquery or javascript.

Comment: Right now I am trying the jQuery masonry as Tamil recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery's `.css()` function:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $(".user").hover(function()
    {
        $(this).css({ "z-index": "9999" });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just using the `z-index` won't help. But combining it with a layout that looks like this:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="content">
        <!-- Your box content -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Style:

.box {
    float: left;
    position:relative;
    overflow:visible;
}

.content {
    position:absolute;
}

To overlap it's important, that a row has a higher `z-index` than it's previous one.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an idea:

You could have each item sit in a `position: relative` div, then when the item is hovered or whatever event that grows the item, give the item `position: relative; left: 0; top: 0;` and change the height.

Position absolute will take it out of its line and make it look like it is still there so none of the other divs will move.